# In DB2 9.7.7 and later, how do you obtain log snapshot status via JDBC?

Tags: db2-luw

**Current manual process:**
Working from a command line, I use this:

Step 1: Take a DB2 status snapshot in DB2CMD or DB2CC

```
get snapshot for database on mydb
```

Step 2: Interpret the DB2 status snapshot - use the figures

```
Appl id holding the oldest transaction     = 22875  **
Log to be redone for recovery (Bytes)      = 21777671554
Log accounted for by dirty pages (Bytes)   = 544881

Node number                                = 0
File number of first active log            = 20611  **
File number of last active log             = 21276  **
File number of current active log          = 21276  **
File number of log being archived          = Not applicable
```

My goal is to replace this manual process with a simple process that runs in my JEE container. I want to obtain the figures tagged with ** to interpret in a program rather than manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the snapshot views, something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
  appl_id_oldest_xact, 
  first_active_log, 
  last_active_log, 
  current_active_log 
FROM 
  sysibmadm.snapdb d , 
  sysibmadm.snapdetaillog l 
WHERE 
  l.dbpartitionnum = d.dbpartitionnum
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks!